# How to deploy a static website to AWS S3 using nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js

I am still new to React and I started writing a static website using Nextjs. But when I want to deploy to AWS S3 I have some problems. I used to use webpack only and when I type `yarn build` I get a dist file and it is easy for me to just upload the content inside the dist file to the S3 bucket.

However after using Nextjs for SSR I found that after I build the project I get a `.next` file with `cache`, `server`, and `static` subfiles as well as `BUILD_ID`, `build-manifest.json`, `react-loadable-manifest.json`,`records.json`. I have no clue what I should upload to S3 and what those files mean.

It may be a silly question but I have already spent more than a day trying to find the solution.

Comment: You also need to use `next export` after building.  https://nextjs.org/docs#static-html-export

Comment: in my package.json,  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node index.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node index.js"
  },  when I yarn export or next export.It just shows an error

Comment: S3 is a file hosting service.  You cannot use SSR with it, and instead need to statically generate (see the link), or host on a server (EC2 for example)

Comment: I added nextjs framework in my old project which is already deployed in S3 so that's why I want to replace my old dist content in my S3 bucket. I have added "export": "npm run build && next export" in my package.json and type yarn export but there are no any html file

Comment: when I run the script  yarn export ,It gives me ''Error: Cannot export when target is not server. https://err.sh/zeit/next.js/next-export-serverless''

Answer (score 1):

You can change package.json as follows.

```
"build": "next build && next export",
```

Then, you can run "yarn build". It will generate top-level directory /out in your project. Upload all contents in the folder by using the command for convenience.

```
aws s3 sync ./out s3://your-s3-bucket-name
```

Make sure you have set your bucket to serve static website and have the following bucket policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: You don't have to open up the entire bucket. Add "--acl public-read" to the aws tool to make individual items public instead.

Answer (score 1):

Original question is very old, if you arrived here using a search, and receive `Error: Cannot export when target is not server` - make sure you remove target
`target: 'serverless'` from `next.config.js`

Otherwise, follow the answer above from @R.Cha https://stackoverflow.com/a/62465471/13749957 which summarizes the docs here and adds S3 specific steps - https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export